# Nginx Redirecting URL (301) with Query String to Final Destination in Single Chain

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, redirection, querystring

I need help with nginx redirection

I want to redirect:

```
example.com/new-clock/?bc=search&search_id=202 to www.example.com
```

I have used this code in nginx config

```
rewrite ^/new-clock/?bc=search&search_id=202$ https://www.example.com/ permanent;
```

But it shows 404, when I remove the query string (?bc=search&search_id=202) and keep only

```
rewrite ^/new-clock/$ https://www.example.com/ permanent;
```

then it redirects to www.example.com/?bc=search&search_id=202

I want it to redirect to www.example.com only, dont want query string in final destination.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you:

```
rewrite ^/new-clock/$ https://www.example.com/ permanent;
```

Then just change the `permanent` to `redirect` at the end of line.

Best regards.

Comment: No, its not working. It show query string at the end of destination url. How to strip the query string?